# Axes at minimum extent, no padding, in plots of raster* objects

Tags: r

Is there a way to ensure that the box around a plot matches the raster extents exactly? In the following there is a gap above and below or to the left and right of the raster depending on the device proportions:

```
require(raster)
r = raster()
r[]= 1
plot(r, xlim=c(xmin(r), xmax(r)), ylim=c(ymin(r), ymax(r)))
```

One element of the problem with raster objects is that `asp=1` to ensure proper display. The following basic scatterplot has the same issue when `asp=1`:

```
plot(c(1:10), c(1:10), asp=1)
```

Try `vectorplot(r)` from the rasterVis package to see what I want the axes to look like.

EDIT:

Solutions need to play nice with SpatialPoints overlays, not showing points outside the specified raster limits:

```
require(raster)
require(maptools)

# Raster
r = raster()
r[]= 1

# Spatial points
x = c(-100, 0, 100)
y = c(100, 0, 100)
points = SpatialPoints(data.frame(x,y))

plot(r, xlim=c(xmin(r), xmax(r)), ylim=c(ymin(r), ymax(r)))
plot(points, add=T)
```

Comment: Good question. I've wondered that that myself, recently, and am glad you thought to ask here.

Comment: Interestingly, this renders perfectly on my R setup. I use R-2.11 64bit on Win7, and the yellow background completely fills the raster extents.

Comment: I'm R-2.13.1 Win7, x64. It fills the raster extent, but not the entire plotted box (the axes are larger than the extent).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You'd probably do best to go with one of the `lattice`-based functions for plotting spatial raster objects provided by the `raster` and `rasterVis` packages.  You discovered one of them in `vectorplot()`, but `spplot()` or `levelplot()` better match your needs in this case.

(The `base graphics`-based `plot()` method for `"RasterLayer"` objects just doesn't allow any easy way for you to set axes with the appropriate aspect ratio. For anyone interested, I go into more detail about why that's so in a section at the bottom of the post.)

As an example of the kind of plot that `levelplot()` produces:

```
require(raster)
require(rasterVis)

## Create a raster and a SpatialPoints object.
r <- raster()
r[] <- 1:ncell(r)
SP <- spsample(Spatial(bbox=bbox(r)), 10, type="random")

## Then plot them    
levelplot(r, col.regions = rev(terrain.colors(255)), cuts=254, margin=FALSE) +
layer(sp.points(SP, col = "red"))

## Or use this, which produces the same plot.
# spplot(r, scales = list(draw=TRUE), 
#        col.regions = rev(terrain.colors(255)), cuts=254) +
# layer(sp.points(SP, col = "red"))
```

[image]

Either of these methods may still plot some portion of the symbol representing points that fall just outside of the plotted raster. If you want to avoid *that* possibility, you can just subset your `SpatialPoints` object to remove any points falling outside of the raster. Here's a simple function that'll do that for you:

```
## A function to test whether points fall within a raster's extent
inExtent <- function(SP_obj, r_obj) {
    crds <- SP_obj@coord
    ext  <- extent(r_obj)
    crds[,1] >= ext@xmin  &  crds[,1] <= ext@xmax &
    crds[,2] >= ext@ymin  &  crds[,2] <= ext@ymax
}
## Remove any points in SP that don't fall within the extent of the raster 'r'
SP <- SP[inExtent(SP, r), ]
```

---

**Additional weedy detail about why it's hard to make `plot(r)` produce snugly fitting axes**

When `plot` is called on an object of type `raster`, the raster data is (ultimately) plotted using either `rasterImage()` or `image()`. Which path is followed depends on: (a) the type of device being plotted to; and (b) the value of the `useRaster` argument in the original `plot()` call.

**In either case, the plotting region is set up in a way which produces axes that fill the plotting region, rather than in a way that gives them the appropriate aspect ratio.**

Below, I show the chain of functions that's called on the way to this step, as well as the call that ultimately sets up the plotting region. In both cases, there appears to be no simple way to alter both the extent and the aspect ratio of the axes that are plotted.

- `useRaster=TRUE`

  ```
  ## Chain of functions dispatched by `plot(r, useRaster=TRUE)`
  getMethod("plot", c("RasterLayer", "missing"))
  raster:::.plotraster2
  raster:::.rasterImagePlot

  ## Call within .rasterImagePlot() that sets up the plotting region
  plot(NA, NA, xlim = e[1:2], ylim = e[3:4], type = "n",
             , xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", asp = asp, ...)

  ## Example showing why the above call produces the 'wrong' y-axis limits
  plot(c(-180,180), c(-90,90), 
       xlim = c(-180,180), ylim = c(-90,90), pch = 16,
       asp = 1,
       main = "plot(r, useRaster=TRUE) -> \nincorrect y-axis limits")
  ```
- `useRaster=FALSE`

  ```
  ## Chain of functions dispatched by `plot(r, useRaster=FALSE)`
  getMethod("plot", c("RasterLayer", "missing"))
  raster:::.plotraster2
  raster:::.imageplot
  image.default

  ## Call within image.default() that sets up the plotting region
  plot(NA, NA, xlim = xlim, ylim = ylim, type = "n", xaxs = xaxs, 
       yaxs = yaxs, xlab = xlab, ylab = ylab, ...)

  ## Example showing that the above call produces the wrong aspect ratio
  plot(c(-180,180), c(-90,90), 
       xlim = c(-180,180), ylim = c(-90,90), pch = 16,
       main = "plot(r,useRaster=FALSE) -> \nincorrect aspect ratio")
  ```

Comment: Do you ever get striping when displaying raster with levelplot?

Comment: @Benjamin -- The only time I saw any striping was when I initially uploaded a pdf image of the above plot to SO, and was then viewing the result with my Firefox browser. Viewed with Adobe, the original pdf looks fine. In what formats are you saving the images, and with what are you viewing them? (I ask because this almost certainly likely has more to do with those factors than with anything about `levelplot`.)

Comment: Even when displaying on screen I see striping. Saving to png or pdf has same issue. My raster is quite large, maybe it is leaving rows out?

Comment: @Benjamin -- FYI, I just now added an explanation of why I think there's no easy way to get the desired plot using `plot()`. I've tried to keep it as short as possible, and so put most of the info needed to track this down into the code blocks. Thanks again for asking this interesting and useful question.

Comment: @Benjamin -- Depending on how large `ncell(r)` is, you might want to try setting the `maxpixels` argument higher than its default value of `1e5` (for `levelplot()`) or 50000 (for `spplot()`). Both functions include a preliminary step in which the full set of pixels is subsampled if it's larger than `maxpixels`.  Please let me know if playing around with that setting solves the problem.

Comment: @Benjamin -- Out of curiosity, did playing with `maxpixels` get rid of the striping you were seeing? (I ask because I'm new to `raster` as well, but will be using it a lot, so want to know its potential weaknesses/pitfalls.)  Thanks!

Comment: Yes and no. It seems to be a display issue, the striping changes pattern when I resize the plot interactively. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Good. That jibes with my own experience. If I learn anything more about that over time, I'll drop you a line here on this thread. Cheers.

Comment: Experienced some stripping with levelplot, seems to resolve when changing the width/height of the png to something  bit smaller.

Answer (score 1):

Man, I got stumped and ended up just turning the foreground color off to plot. Then you can take advantage of the fact that the raster plot method calls `fields:::image.plot`, which lets you *just* plot the legend (a second time, this time showing the ink!). This is inelegant, but worked in this case:

```
    par("fg" = NA)
    plot(r, xlim = c(xmin(r), xmax(r)), ylim = c(ymin(r), ymax(r)), axes = FALSE)
    par(new = TRUE,"fg" = "black")
    plot(r, xlim = c(xmin(r), xmax(r)), ylim = c(ymin(r), ymax(r)), axes = FALSE, legend.only = TRUE)
    axis(1, pos = -90, xpd = TRUE)
    rect(-180,-90,180,90,xpd = TRUE)
    ticks <- (ymin(r):ymax(r))[(ymin(r):ymax(r)) %% 20 == 0]
    segments(xmin(r),ticks,xmin(r)-5,ticks, xpd = TRUE)
    text(xmin(r),ticks,ticks,xpd=TRUE,pos=2)
        title("sorry, this could probably be done in some more elegant way")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this does not work for me as I need to overlay SpatialPoints objects, which should be masked if located outside the raster extent.

Answer (score 1):

This is way I solved this problem

```
require(raster)
r = raster()

# default for raster is 180 row by 360 cols =  64800 cells
# fill with some values to make more interesting
r[]= runif(64800, 1, 1000)

# Set margin for text
par(mar=c(2, 6, 6, 2))

# Set some controls for the raster cell colours and legend

MyBrks<-c(0,1,4,16,64,256,1E20)                                  
MyLbls<-c("<1","<4","<16","<64","<256","<Max")       
MyClrs<-c("blue","cyan","yellow","pink","purple","red")  

# Plot raster without axes or box or legend
# Note xlim and ylim don't seem do much unless you want to trim x and y
plot(r, 
     col=MyClrs,
     axes=FALSE,
     box=FALSE,
     legend=FALSE
     )

# Set up the ranges and intervals for axes - you can get the min max
# using xmin(r) and ymax(r) and so on if you like
MyXFrm <- -180
MyXTo <- 180
MyXStp <- 60
MyYFrm <- -90
MyYTo <- 90
MyYStp <- 30

# Plot the axes
axis(1,tick=TRUE,pos=ymin(r),las=1,at=seq(MyXFrm,MyXTo ,MyXStp )) 
axis(2,tick=TRUE,pos=xmin(r),las=1,at=seq(MyYFrm ,MyYTo ,MyYStp ))

# Plot the legend use xpd to plot the legend outside the plot region
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend(MyXTo ,MyYTo , 
       legend=MyLbls[1:6],                    
       col= MyClrs,             
       fill=Clrs[1:6],                            
       bg=rgb(0,0,0,0.85),           
       cex=0.9,
       text.col="white",
       text.font=2,                      
       border=NA                 
      ) 

# Add some axis labels and a title
text(-220,0,"Y",font=2)
text(0,-130,"X",font=2) 
text(0,120,"My Raster",font=4,cex=1.5)
```

[image: What the plot looks like]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best (or simplest) solution is to use `image()`:

```
library(raster)

# Raster
r = raster()
r[]= rnorm(ncell(r))

# Spatial points
x = c(-100, 0, 100)
y = c(100, 0, 100)
points = SpatialPoints(data.frame(x,y))

# plot
image(r)
plot(points, add=T, pch=16, cex=2)
```

[image: raster plot with the image function]