# Plot raster file

Tags: r, plot, raster

I have a `dataframe` in which values `c` are specified for Cartesian coordinates `(x, y)`. I use `plot()` and the result has too much space in Y-axis. Is there a way to edit that?

```
library(raster)
x <- c(1:60)
y <- c(2:5)
c <- rnorm(60)
Data1 <- data.frame(x, y, c)
raster1 <- rasterFromXYZ(Data1)
plot(raster1)
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this isn't easy to control. Your best option will be to play around with the size and shape of the device to which you plot the raster. [See this question and its two answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29828821/r-raster-avoid-white-space-when-plotting/29831084#29831084) -- one by me and one by the **raster** package's primary author -- for closely related advice and code. Or use `spplot()` or `rasterVis::levelplot()`, which are more sophisticated in their adjustment of the plot's x and y limits. (Try `spplot(raster1)` to see what I mean by that.)

Comment: `image()` also gets the job done and that's a part of the raster package.

Comment: @Badger -- The downside there is that it loses the 1-to-1 aspect ratio that you usually want when plotting a map. And if you do `image(raster1, asp=1)`, to get the aspect ratio right, you're right back to the same problem the OP started with...

Comment: Finally, [here is a more complete explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9404998/980833) of **why** this is so hard to accomplish, using `plot()`.

Answer (score -1):

While not a fix, it helps to note that in `plot()`, `xlim` and `ylim` end up providing the `max` and `min`.

Obviously, it's handled differently in the raster library. When I use `plot(raster1, ylim=c(2,5))`, the axis isn't adjusted at all.  However, if you use `plot(raster1, xlim=c(0,20))` clearly affects the x-axis.

I'm not sure why it won't affect the y-axis.